# Algorithm for drawing pixels on top of each other (with alpha)

Tags: algorithm, graphics2d

I am looking for the algorithm that is used to compute output pixel value when drawing source pixel on top of destination pixel. When the source pixel doesn't have an alpha, then obviously I can set the output pixel to be equal to source pixel. What about when the source has alpha? How do I compute the new alpha and RGB values?

Comment: Illustration: http://jsfiddle.net/rbChu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is just a weighted sum of the destination and the source.

```
output = alpha * source + (1 - alpha) * destination
```

Do this for each of the three RGB channels.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends what blending algorithm you want to use: multiplicative, additive, etc. Additive, for example, would just add elements together:

`RGBA(1, 2, 3, 4) + RGBA(5, 6, 7, 8) = RGBA(6, 8, 10, 12)`

Multiplicative blending (obviously) multiplies (in some cases cross-multiplies) the RGBA datums. You can also subtract channels, divide, or do any other fancy algebraic math. Regardless of what blending method you choose to implement, the alpha channel is generally additive - unless you have a specific reason for it not to be (i.e masking).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are also running into premultiplied alpha vs. well, not-premultiplied alpha. The default should be premultiplied, though, so I'll use that.

The formula is simple:

```
DestinationRGB = ImageRGB+(1-ImageAlpha)*DestinationRGB
```